# Why Countries Element in super forms plugin Empty?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Why Countries Element in super forms plugin Empty ????

Comment: I strongly suspect this question would be more suitable for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, but you should also give more details.

Comment: **Super Forms WordPress Plugin**
Countries Element is a dropdown who have all countries and costumer choose from it his Nationality . it is empty , doesn't have any country in it.

Comment: That's not really much more information - and I still see no sign that this is really a *programming* issue which would be on-topic on this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming issue, as described.